# How to pass file as argument in .desktop file for wine application

Tags: 11.04, wine

I actually want to ask two questions:

1. Where can I find more about available arguments/parameters shortcuts for Exec entry in desktop files (like %U, %u, %f...)
2. Main question, how to pass file as argument on .desktop launcher for wine application?

I found searching here this suggestion: `z:%f` which is of no use to me, as if I simply run .desktop file without passing file on it, it assumes that argument is `z:` and starts scanning `z:` "drive"

---

Example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Some Windows program
Exec=wine "program.exe" z:%f
Type=Application
Terminal=false
MimeType=application/docbook+xml
```

I want to drop XML file on my custom .desktop launcher for this wine application and I can this way. Problem is that if I click on launcher icon to evoke this program, argument `z:` is always passed on it and that's not acceptable

Comment: What are you trying to do btw? Can you add an example?

Comment: Hey Bruno ;) I thought it is clear - I made desktop file (purpose - launcher) for wine application and I want to be able to pass file on it. Above `z:%f` workaround is no good as whenever I launch this wine application argument `z:` is passed on it and I want to avoid that

Comment: So you have a windows program called (ie) `application.exe` that you want to pass the current selected file in nautilus to it ie `file.txt`?

Comment: Sorry I should have added example in my first post. I added it now

Comment: I have been having a look around this till now and the only other option for this is a script placed in the `exec` line that checks for a `%f`, if it exists launch the application on the file, if not just launch the application. Care for it or is it not an option?

Comment: Bruno, I was thinking the same about one-liner in `Exec:` that checks argument. I was not sure about other possible placeholders for arguments in `Exec:` - are there others like %U, %u, %f - those are only ones I know. And I can't meaningfully google for "ubuntu + desktop + agruments" or similar as all terms are too weary. I thought to try without `z:` expecting wine program not to be complain about missing drive letter, but unfortunately to me it expects full qualified file path

Comment: Think a script is of the order here, it should do the work for you, I can make one if you want (I am sure you probably can also).

Comment: Can do it, thanks for considering. I'll just look around for other possibilities and post here if I find better way

Comment: If you find it post it (and drop a comment) I am sure you will get a butt load of upvotes (you will get from me for sure, this is a nice question).

Answer (score 10):

This is best I can so far (Notepad example)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Notepad
Exec=sh -c "echo %f | sed 's/^\//z:\//' | xargs wine /home/zetah/.wine/drive_c/windows/notepad.exe"
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Wine
MimeType=text/plain
```

I expect better answers considering I'm beginner

Answer (score 6):

For the first question, you can take a look at the [Desktop Entry Specification - The `Exec` key](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html#exec-variables)

Comment: the link to the always most recent version: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables

Answer (score 2):

An Exec line with a pipe of **winepath** to xargs, used with proper quoting and their -0 options, works flawlessly in Ubuntu 14.04 for opening single and multiple files.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env sh -c "winepath -w -0 %F | WINEPREFIX='/home/your_user_name/.wine' xargs -0 wine 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Some Vendor\\\\SomeProgram.exe'"
```

Comment: Old thread, but for anyone walking in here from google in 2023, this is the solution that worked for me. The other answers on this page would not even run my application.

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on zetah's answer. This works for passing multiple files to the program. The %f is changed to %F (upper case) to pass all the files dropped, replacing the ^ (for the beginning of the line) with enough of the path name to make it more likely unique, the 'g' at the end of the sed command to cause the replacement to repeat for all files passed and finally the $ instead of the / so that the \ escape characters are not necessary.

```
Exec=sh -c "echo %F | sed 's$/home$z:/home$g' | xargs wine /home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Progs/Boxer/b.exe"
```

I also moved the program to be executed to a path where the pathname has no spaces, so I moved my boxer editor from:

```
/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Boxer Text Editor/
```

to:

```
/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Progs/Boxer/
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a tiny [Python script](https://github.com/ivanslf/wine-launcher) which converts Unix-style paths into Wine path format.

Download the [zip](https://github.com/ivanslf/wine-launcher/archive/master.zip), extract **wine-launcher.py** into your home folder and edit your .desktop file like this:

```
Exec=python ~/wine-launcher.py "program.exe" %F
```

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of hackish solutions posted in this thread. Here's a much better solution that deals with multiple files and with spaces in filenames.

Create the .desktop file as you usually do, and simply use this Exec line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env bash -c "printf 'z:%%q\\n' %F | WINEPREFIX='/home/<your username>/.wine' xargs wine 'C:\\Path\\to the executable\\app.exe'"
```

**Edit**: If your application can handle multiple files in a single instance (for example a multi-tabbed PDF viewer) and you want the current instance to be auto-focused whenever you launch a new file then you need to do the following:

- Add this line to the .desktop file: `StartupWMClass=app.exe`
- Use this Exec command:

  ```
  Exec=/usr/bin/env bash -c "(printf 'z:%%q\\n' %F | WINEPREFIX='/home/<your username>/.wine' xargs wine 'C:\\Path\\to the executable\\app.exe' &); xdotool windowactivate \$(xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class \"app.exe\")"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that just worked for me on a RHEL 6.3 box after some trial and error and reading the Desktop Entry Specification. It's not specific to wine with arguments but it should work with something like `Exec=wine \"filename.exe\"`.

Hope it helps someone as it took me some searching to get it to work.

I think you have to use double quotes and escape them as well as any special characters using a backslash.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Ansys User Lic Prefs 12.1
GenericName=Ansys User Lic Prefs 12.1
Comment=Ansys User License Prefs 12.1
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=anslic_admin \"\-userprefs121\"
Icon=ansysLogo_16x16.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Ansys;
```